# Is it possible to reset the file limit counter on p:fileUpload?

Tags: primefaces

We have a `p:fileUpload` to let a user upload an avatar image. If he wants he should be able to upload different ones in quick succession without having to reload the view; this would replace his current avatar every time. However, if `fileLimit` is set to 1, he has to reload the page to be able to use the component again. If it is any more (or unlimited (=0)) he is able to upload multiple files at once, which makes little sense. The `multiple`-attribute, if set to false, only restricts the file browsing-dialog to *selecting* a single file; it can still be opened again to add more files at will. Is it possible to allow uploading any amount of files, but never more than one file at once? We are using Primefaces 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with this workaround, that doesn't reset the file limit counter itself, but instead resets the fileUpload component so the counter resets too. This way the parameter `fileLimit` limits the number of files per upload, and not per pageload.

First lets define a `reset()` function in the PrimeFaces FileUpload component:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.FileUpload.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.clearMessages();
    return this.init(this.cfg);
}
```

This method resets the component by calling `init()` with the current configuration.

Then we just have to call this method in the FileUploadEvent like this:

```
public void uploadFile(FileUploadEvent event) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('fileUploadWidgetVar').reset();");
}
```

And now everytime you handle the uploaded files, the counter resets because the component resets too.

Comment: Where exactly in the xhtml does that reset function go?  Is it in a script block or something?

Comment: The first snippet of code should go in a script block because its a javascript function. The second snippet is an example on how to use that javascript function from the ManagedBean.

Comment: This is a fantastic example, but you don't need to include that java code, you can just call the reset method from the p:fileUpload's oncomplete method: oncomplete="PF('fileUploadWidget').reset()"

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem. Adding update="@this" to the p:fileUpload tag solved it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, does not need to add JS functions or force the upload when the file is selected. And it works as of Primefaces 5.3.

Comment: This is the key

Answer (score 1):

Have you utilized the `auto="true"` statement? Keep in mind that the default setting in Primefaces does not automatically upload files unless activated by the user.

Comment: That's pretty fair for a workaround, even if not a solution. I think we can just do that.